# Xcode Nested IBAction

Tags: iphone, xcode, random, nested

Hey I have some code generating and displaying a random word from a list like this:

```
-(IBAction)secondWord {
    int text = rand() % 2;
    switch (text) {
        case 0:
            secondWord.text = @"random1";
            break;
        case 1:
            secondWord.text = @"random2";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

I have this twice with 2 buttons changing the text on 2 labels. Is there a way I can set up another action to execute both of these IBActions at once. Thus allowing the words to be randomly generated individually and at the same time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
-(IBAction)allWords {
    [self firstWord];
    [self secondWord];
}
```

Something like this? You can call those actions just like any other function.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why this doesn't work. Please provide some more info about what's going on. Are there any warnings in the console? You can try adding some NSLog() output to see if that action is actually getting called.